# How can I prompt for device password before applying updates?

Tags: password, update-manager, gui, luks, prompt

I have an encrypted boot partition on an USB drive. How can I prompt the user to insert the USB drive, and decrypt it before applying system updates?

I can write the script to decrypt and mount the partition, but I don't know how to run it before the update process, and how to display a GUI window prompting the user for password.

Comment: "but I don't know how to run it before the update process, and how to display a GUI window prompting the user for password." you add the update command to the script the same way you added the mount command. No need for a GUI. The password will be asked on command line too. (ie `sudo apt install update` would be the command)

Comment: I was thinking more like when the user clicks "update" in update manager, to prevent him to apply the updates without the /boot present

Comment: Check out zenity; it's very handy for adding graphical windows and prompts to your scripts, and I think it comes standard with Ubuntu.